# CMAKE error project files invalid ; does not contain cmakelists.txt

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I am trying to compile the code from the following website on a 64 bit windows computer..

https://dms.sztaki.hu/en/project/gaussian-mixture-modeling-gmm-es-fisher-vector-toolkit

I am getting the following errors:

> 1) error configuration.. project files may be invalid
>   2) CMake Error: The source directory "/GMM_Fisher_toolkit/GMM_CUDA_src" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
>   Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.

How can I compile it?

Comment: I can't immediately spot a source download from your link but, at a guess, are you regenerating the makefile.  From memory, cmake creates makefiles using absolute paths so they typically have to be regenerated for every source checkout.

Answer (score 1):

To create an out-of-source build:

1. Extract your source code to ~/src/test
2. Create a folder ~/build/test
3. Goto: ~/build/test
4. Run: cmake ../../src/test
5. Run: make