# When i cmake mysql on Oracle linux,there was an error:"cmake error: the source directory does not appear to contain cmakelist.txt "

Tags: c++, mysql, linux, cmake

I tried to install MySQL5.6.16 on Oracle Linux, my source package is `mysql-advanced-5.6.16-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64.tar.gz`.

1. I use commond `tar` to unzip my mysql package.

   tar -zvxf mysql-advanced-5.6.16-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64.tar.gz
2. I use `cd` to enter the folder `mysql-advanced-5.6.16-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64`
3. I use commond `cmake .`

Then, there was an

> CmakeError:the source directory . does not appear to contain cmakelist.txt

Who can tell me why?

PS: I searched the error, somebody said that maybe the source package is not the right one. If so, which package should I download?

Comment: look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402423/cmake-error-project-files-invalid-does-not-contain-cmakelists-txt

Comment: The name of the archive probably suggest that you downloaded already compiled binaries. There are probably no sources codes at all.

Comment: have you created a build directory?? you should execute the cmake .. from the build directory.
from the tutorial:
`Create a new directory for creating build mkdir build cd build Once you are inside the build directory. Pass the command`

Comment: i created a directory in /usr/local/mysql, and i used "cmake /root/soft/mysql-advanced-5.6.16-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64" under directory /usr/local/mysql,but there was still CmakeError:source directory does not appear to contain cmakelist.txt